# How to programmatically fill or create filer.fields.image.FilerImageField?

Tags: django, django-filer

I have some model class with a filer.fields.image.FilerImageField as a field.

```
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField
class ModelName(Model):
    icon = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How to programmatically create or fill an icon field if I have a local path to an image file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can approach it this way:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.files import File
from filer.models import Image

filename = 'file'
filepath = 'path/to/file'
user = User.objects.get(username='testuser')
with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
    file_obj = File(f, name=filename)
    image = Image.objects.create(owner=user,
                                 original_filename=filename,
                                 file=file_obj)
    instance = ModelName(icon=image)
    instance.save()
```

image is an instance of `filer.models.Image`, assign it to icon attribute of a Model instance, `FilerImageField` will handle it for you.

Comment: ValueError: Cannot assign "<File: file>": "Course.icon" must be a "Image" instance.

Comment: @user2120409 Oh, image must be an instance of `filer.models.Image`.I have updated my answer, try again please.

Comment: In python 3, we must explicitly say that the file is binary and write: `with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:`.

Comment: Also, open `filepath` with `"rb"` mode as it is a binary file.

Comment: Even in Python 2, @PhilippZedler , "rb" is required if you want it to work correctly in Windows. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I tried and tried this, but I had to do a case of instance_of_modelName.icon_id = image.  Admittedly, my case was an add-on to an existing model, so I couldn't create new.